# How to Add Custom Attribute Variable in Invoice Magento 1.9.2?

Tags: magento2, database, magento-1

I have created two custom attribute code. I assigned one of these code on product. I want to show product name alongwith this code in invoice. How can i implement this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use 2 differents way:

1. Use free extension **Easy PDF Invoice - Custom Variables**  https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/16526/
2. Create a new module. Good example by Inchoo: http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-attribute-to-magentos-pdf-invoice/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am using Easy PDF Invoice. Now I can add custom variable in my invoice. I also need to add same variable in order confirmation email. how can i implement it?